# Javascript events using H.datalens.Provider

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

Are there any events to subscribe to using

H.datalens.Provider

? So one can know when all data has been loaded for example, or if there was an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. There is an "update" event being triggered when the data gets updated (see https://developer.here.com/documentation/geovisualization/datalens/h-datalens-provider.html) but I do recall it triggering multiple times. Afaik there's no easy way to know the data has finished loading.

A trick I've seen using is listening to the event and starting a timeout, resetting it every time a new update event gets triggered. When the timeout is finally able to execute, the updates are over. This is not by any means a good solution, but might be of help.

Comment: This both works:

`provider.addEventListener('update',function(){console.log('update')})`

`$(provider).on('update',function(){console.log('updatej')})`